# How to pass variables in sed commands

Tags: bash, csv, for-loop, sed

I am trying to pass this line of code through my script:
`row=8

title="sometitle"

sed -i $rowi"$title" hi.csv`

where `row` represents the row I want to insert something in a csv file and `title` represents the content I want to insert into that row. The problem is `sed` won't pass the `$row`. I can't just use the command `sed -i 8i"sometitle" hi.csv` because the `row` and `title` variables change since im passing this `sed` command in a forloop. Is there any way for me to pass variables in a `sed` command? thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your command and I guess you have to point out to the shell what the variable is, so you will have to surround it with curly braces, like this:

```
sed -i ${row}i"$title" hi.csv
```

---

**EDIT**: Another attempt to avoid an error (see comments):

```
sed "${row} i\
> $title
> " hi.csv
```

Comment: i get this error:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 1: expected \ after `a', `c' or `i'`

Comment: @user2143205: It works for my version (`sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`). Look at the docs how you have to use the insert in your version. It usually works to put it in the following line and escape the newline with a backslash. The error message says something about it. **EDIT**: I've added the same command but split in different lines. I think it's more accepted for different versions.

Comment: well despite the error it still does what it is suppose to so thank you very much! I'm really a beginner but I'm glad I can come to this community to ask for help despite how much a amateur I am. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
row=8
title=="sometitle"
sed "${row} i\\^J${title}" hi.csv > YourFinal.csv
```

Tested under ksh/AIX (so sed doesn't have -i option) [^J is a new line obtain with CTRL+V+J]